# You do not have permission to view this page or an error occured

Tags: security, permissions

I have installed a package in my org. But when I try to run a page from this package I am getting an error that

> Error 
>   You do not have permission to view this page or an error occured.
>   Please contact your administrator

[image]

But I have logged as system admin but even then I am getting this error. I went through the admin profile but I am able to found the app and all classes, pages and object are accessible to admin but even then I am getting this error. Please guide me what might be the issue.

Comment: you may like to contact app vendor as that can be a custom error that an app vendor might have put on page.can you show screenshot of error message

Comment: @MohithShrivastava please do have a look on my question I have edited the question.

Comment: It's possible that you might have missed some configuration while setting up the package. I would suggest that you check it once. In case everything seems fine, then as @MohithShrivastava said, you should contact the app developers.

Comment: There might be some validation in the package allowing access to only certain profiles. The error message does not look like the standard access error message.

Comment: Apps quite often have a permission set that needs to be applied, you sure you haven't missed assigning that?